# My code is producing extra <a> links

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

I'm not sure why, but I think something in my CSS is creating duplicates of my HTML code. I'm fairly new to CSS, so maybe I'm missing something!

Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="once">
<div class="third" id="third">
<a href="http://69.195.124.168/~onceweso/?page_id=8" class="post" style="background-image: url(http://media.mydogspace.com.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/puppy-500x350.jpg);">
<div class="post-overlay">
<div class="post-header">
<h2 class="homepage-title">The List</h2>
</div>
</div></a>

<a href="http://69.195.124.168/~onceweso/?page_id=8" class="post" style="background-image: url(http://media.mydogspace.com.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/puppy-500x350.jpg);">
<div class="post-overlay">
<div class="post-header">
<h2 class="homepage-title">The List</h2>
</div>
</div></a>

<a href="http://69.195.124.168/~onceweso/?page_id=8" class="post" style="background-image: url(http://media.mydogspace.com.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/puppy-500x350.jpg);">
<div class="post-overlay">
<div class="post-header">
<h2 class="homepage-title">The List</h2>
</div>
</div></a>
</div>
</section>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

section.once {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
 }

.third {
    margin-top: -3.95%;
}

.third .post {
    display: block;
    width: 30.7%;
    margin-top: 3.95%;
    padding: 10%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.post-header {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    }

.homepage-title {
    font-size: 1.375em;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #222;
    word-break: break-word;
    -ms-word-break: break-word;
}

.post-overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    opacity: 0;
}

.post-header {
    bottom: 35px;
}

::selection {
    background: #444;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

This is the URL with sample images: http://69.195.124.168/~onceweso/?page_id=544
(password: once)

Eventually my goal is to add a text overlay.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can't put `<div>` inside `<a>`.

Because that's illegal, the browser implicitly closes the `<a>` tag first.

Answer (score 1):

Your code includes anchors surrounding a div, which is incorrect because you cannot actually anchor a div.

This article should help with your goal of adding a text overlay: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/textoverimage/